# GraphQL Query access all transformed json files within a folder located in subdirectories

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a project structure like so:

```
-$PROJECT
--src
---data
----projects
-----project1
------project.json
------images
-------project1-preview.png
-----project2
------project.json
-------images
...
```

And so on, for however many projects. I could query these project.json files when they were named the title of the project and within a `projects` folder using `allProjectsJson` in graphQl, however now they are within subfolders within `projects`. I can only query them individually as allProject1Json and so on. Is there a way to query allProjectsJson so I get all the project.json files?

I can find my projects files by querying `allFile` with a filter for json files, however, these files are not transformed json so I can't access the elements.

In my gatsby-config file I am importing src/data as a source for files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my answer at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20734:

Ahh, I see what you mean :)
luckily `gatsby-transformer-json` has a plugin option that will help get you unstuck!

It's the [typeName](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-json/#configuration-options) option. You should be able to check for a field on each JSON node, and use that as the type name. Something like this:

```js
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-json`,
      options: {
        typeName: ({ node, object, isArray }) =>
          object.project ? `Project` : `Json`,
      },
    },
```

That way anything with the field `project` defined will show up as `allProject { ... }`, where any other json files will show up as `allJson { ... }`

```
{
  allProject {
    nodes {
      project
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "allProject": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "project": "project1"
        },
        {
          "project": "project2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My project works very similarly. Here's how I have my `gatsby-config.js` setup:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...,
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'project',  // Identifier. Will then be queried as `allProjectsJson`
        path: './data',   // Source folder containing the JSON files
      },
    },
    ...,
  ]
};
```

Example JSON file:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Hello",
    "description": "World",
    "url": "https://www.google.com",
    "image": "./images/img1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "World",
    "description": "Hello",
    "url": "https://www.google.com",
    "image": "./images/img2.jpg"
  },
]
```

Example query:

```graphql
query projects {
  allProjectsJson {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        description
        url
        image {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have my projects split into individual json files within respective folders containing the project.json file and an images folder. Here is code sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-river-gqf3o?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark I couldn't figure out how to recompile the project in order to do a graphQl query on the json files.

Comment: I see the issue a lot clearer now. I'm assuming you did, but just in case: have you tried setting your `gatsby-source-filesystem` path to be `${__dirname}/src/data/projects`? If so, what results does this yield?

Comment: I tried it in the codesandbox and have the same result

Comment: I upvoted you from -1 as I thought that was unfair.