# How to get Gatsby page HTML in graphQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to implement site search with elasticlunr and am following the instructions for gatsby-plugin-elasticlunr-search. I'm stuck trying to build a search index since I can't come up with a graphql query that includes any of my content.

Every example I find shows how to edit gatsby-config.js to populate graphql with markdown content:

```
resolvers: {
      // For any node of type MarkdownRemark, list how to resolve the fields` values
      MarkdownRemark: {
        title: node => node.frontmatter.title,
        tags: node => node.frontmatter.tags,
        path: node => node.frontmatter.path,
      },
    },
```

I don't have any markdown, my content is entirely in HTML and a few JSON files. Is there any way to pull HTML content into graphql so it can be included in a search index?

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the JSON files/content in the same way that the guides does with markdown (as you can see in [Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/sourcing-content-from-json-or-yaml/) or in [this article](https://dimitr.im/using-json-with-gatsby)), however, you may need to create a data structure to populate your HTML since you can't fetch directly the data from an HTML file as it, since it's not inside the Gatsby filesystem, so that Gatsby doesn't know how to create nodes nor GraphQL schema from that content.

The easiest approach is to create a custom data filesystem (JSON, YAML, or markdown files) to populate your HTML and make it dynamic, not "hardcoded" as it is actually (apparently). Once you've set the filesystem and you are able to create queries to gather data and fill your pages/components, you will be able to create queries to use `elasticlunr`.

Resources:

- https://itnext.io/reading-data-from-a-json-file-with-gatsby-graphql-572b18ab98a
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20734
- [GraphQL Query access all transformed json files within a folder located in subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831767/graphql-query-access-all-transformed-json-files-within-a-folder-located-in-subdi)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it sounds like it's simply not possible to get HTML content into GraphQL. We'll use something like Algolia or Google search for now and move this content into JSON or Markdown files later.

Comment: If you deal with Algolia you'll face the same issue, you'll need a query to allow the service something to query (self-experience).

Comment: You're totally right, I assumed Algolia would crawl the generated HTML to generate an index but they do not. Google seems to be our only option for the short term. Thanks again Ferran!

Comment: You can use Netlify. They have an Algolia plugin that runs on each build. So the index will be created on netlify behalf.

Comment: It's still based on a query that you need to provide in order to create an index. You always need to add logic behind crawlers and search engines.

Comment: No its not. They crawl the resulting static html files after build.